# Should I write code that takes advantage of Intellisense?

Tags: oop, f#, functional-programming, intellisense, purely-functional

I am starting with F# and made some progress in understanding the syntax. However, I remain unclear about the best way to use F#'s features. In Python, where I am coming from, there is usually one "best" (almost canonical) way of doing things. Maybe that is also the case for F#, but I have not figured it out. So my questions below are about the best way to use F#, and not technical questions about F#'s syntax.

Recently I saw a video by Dr. Eric Meijer `(C9 Lectures - Functional Programming Fundamentals Chapter 2 of 13)` in which Dr. Meijer praises the dot notation of OOP, observing that it allows Intellisense to display a list of available methods. He laments that such a facility is not available in pure FP, which makes programming so much easier by helping programmers "move forward."

A bit of experimenting showed that of course Intellisense works with F# classes, but also works with F# records, which, like classes, use the dot notation. This means one can shape one's code so as to take advantage of Intellisense without going all the way to write classes (I am assuming that in F# classes are heavier and slower than records, please correct me if I am wrong).

The following code shows two ways of writing code (call them "versions") that perform the same operations:

```
// Create a record type with two values that are functions of two arguments
type AddSub = {add2: int -> int -> int; sub2: int -> int -> int}

// Instantiate a record
let addsub a =
    {add2 = (fun x y -> a + x + y); sub2 = (fun x y -> a - x - y)}

// Returns 7, Intellisense works on (addsub 0).
(addsub 0).add2 3 4
// Returns 3, Intellisense works on (addsub 10).  
(addsub 10).sub2 3 4

// Create two functions of three arguments
let add3 a x y = a + x + y
let sub3 a x y = a - x - y

// Also got 7, no Intellisense facility here
add3 0 3 4
// Also got 3, no Intellisense facility here
sub3 10 3 4
```

This shows that there is an intermediate strategy between pure FP and OOP: creating record types with function values, as above. Such a strategy organizes my code in meaningful units centered about objects (record instances) and allows me to use Intellisense, but lacks some of the features provided by classes, like inheritance and subclass polymorphism (again correct me if I am wrong here).

Coming from an OOP background I feel that if an object like `a` in the code above is somehow more "significant" (I will leave that term undefined) than the parameters x and y such a coding strategy would be justified, both on the grounds of code organization and of the ability to use Intellisense. On the other hand, burned by the complexities of OOP, I would rather remain in the  "pure" FP realm.

Is the use of records a worthwhile compromise between the two extreme alternatives (OOP and pure FP)?

In general, given three alternatives (pure FP, records as above, or classes) what are general guidelines on the circumstances under which one alternative is preferred over the others?

Finally, are there other coding strategies available that would help me organize my code and/or take advantage of Intellisense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Intellisense still works just fine in F#, but at a module level rather than at a class level. I.e., I just typed in `List.` and once I typed the dot, VS Code (with the Ionide plugin providing F# Intellisense) gave me a list of possible completions: `append`, `average`, `averageBy`, `choose`, `chunkBySize`...

To get that benefit from your own functions, put them in a module:

```
module AddSub =
    let add2 x y = x + y
    let sub2 x y = x - y
    let add3 a x y = a + x + y
    let sub3 a x y = a - x - y
```

Now when you type `AddSub.`, after you type the dot, Intellisense will suggest `add2`, `add3`, `sub2`, and `sub3` as possible followups. Yet you've kept your functions "clean" and curryable, in "proper" F# style.

Finally, one other piece of advice about function design. You mentioned having functions in which one parameter (like `a` in the `add3` and `sub3` functions) is somehow more "significant" than the other parameters. In F#, any such parameter should probably be the *last* parameter, because that allows you to put it in a function chain using the `|>` operator, like so:

```
let a = 20
a |> AddSub.add3 5 10 |> AddSub.sub3 2 3  // Result: 30
```

Or rather, using the style that most people prefer when there's a "pipeline" of operations from a single starting value:

```
let a = 20
a
|> AddSub.add3 5 10
|> AddSub.sub3 2 3
// Result: 30
```

Lining up the pipeline vertically becomes more important when there are more operations in it. My rule of thumb is that if there are more than two total "extra" parameters specified in the pipeline (the pipeline above has four "extra" parameters, two each for the `add3` and `sub3` functions), or if any of the "extra" parameters is more complicated than a single value (e.g., if one parameter is an anonymous function like `(fun x -> sprintf "The value of x was %d" x)` or some such), then you should arrange it vertically.

P.S. If you haven't read it yet, read Scott Wlaschin's excellent series on [Thinking Functionally](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/thinking-functionally-intro/). It'll help explain many things about this answer, like why I suggested putting the "most significant" argument last. If you didn't immediately understand my brief comment about how that enables you to use it with the `|>` parameter, or if there was anything else that puzzled you about this answer, then you'll probably get a lot of benefit out of Scott's articles.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I should have thought of modules. I guess what threw me off was that Dr. Meijer complained about not being able to use Intellisense. But he was talking about Haskell, maybe there are no modules or similar facilities in Haskell.

Comment: Yeah the standard practice in Haskell is to import functions from modules, rather than use them qualified, so that's not very Intellisense-friendly.

Comment: @Tarmil afaik, there are autocompletion tools for Haskell now https://github.com/rikvdkleij/intellij-haskell

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty broad, and some of the specific aspects of modules have been covered by @munn already. I wanted to add a few thoughts arising out of my own work on a pretty large F# codebase with a changing team of developers.

Code discoverability rules. Being able to see (via Intellisense) which methods are available for an object is getting more important as your codebase grows. But maybe even more importantly, it helps new joiners to your team, who may not yet know that there is module `X` that has all methods to work with instances of a class/record/etc.

I've found the [F# component design guide](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/) very helpful. It provides a lot of details on how to strike the balance between OOP and functional. For your specific question, see the [section on intrinsic operations](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#-do-use-properties-and-methods-for-operations-intrinsic-to-types), where it says in direct reference to the points you raised:

> Do use properties and methods for operations intrinsic to types.
>   This is called out specifically because some people from a functional programming background avoid the use of object oriented programming together, preferring a module containing a set of functions defining the intrinsic functions related to a type (e.g. length foo rather than foo.Length). But see also the next bullet. In general, in F#, the use of object-oriented programming is preferred as a software engineering device. This strategy also provides some tooling benefits such as Visual Studio’s “Intellisense” feature to discover the methods on a type by “dotting into” an object.

When tempted to write a class hierarchy, think twice whether you can't replace inheritance with a discriminated union type. You can tack on members (static or instance member) as you can with records, classes, etc:

```
type Animal = 
    | Cat | Dog
    member this.Sound = match this with | Cat -> "meow" | Dog -> "bark"
    static member FromString s = function | "cat" -> Cat | "dog" -> Dog | _ -> failwith "nope."
```

Comment: Imho, it's better to keep the type as simple as possible and put the type and its operational functions together in the same module, and keep modules tightly focused around their primary type. Then you stick to using functions everywhere instead of having to awkwardly switch between OOP and FP styles. See e.g. https://gist.github.com/yawaramin/552c25a23549f15556d54954e39f946d

Comment: @Anton -  Thanks for the insights. I confess I was a bit surprised by the advice you quoted. It sounds eminently sensible from a practical point of view, but I expected there was some smart alternative in FP. 
On the class hierarchy, I am not so sure. I am far from being an expert, but it looks to me like your Animal type has to be amended every time a new animal (Lion/roar) enters the scene.  I believe this would be a violation of the Open/Close Principle in SOLID. Still, that would work when I know there is no possibility of new subtypes.